# Connect from My Local Environment vs Cloud Environment MongoDb Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

When we set up our database using MongoDb Atlas we have an option: "Where would you like to connect from?" , and we can choose between "My Local Environment" and "Cloud Environment". Can someone explain the difference to me? Sorry for the amateur question but im a newbie in this topic. THanks in Advance!